# Remove the Emacs menu bar

Tags: emacs, menubar

I tried [Prelude - WikEmacs](https://wikemacs.org/wiki/Prelude),

Every time I open emacs, there is a menu bar at the top:

> File Edit Options Buffers Tools Emacs-Lisp Prelude Projectile Help

[image]

How can I remove it or prevent it from being shown?

Comment: I append to `init.el`, it does not work unfortunately. @Drew

Comment: thank you, it works perfectly, could you please transmit the comment to answer. @Drew

Comment: Done - I put it in an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can disable the menu bar by turning off minor mode `menu-bar-mode`. `C-h f menu-bar-mode` tells you this:

> **`menu-bar-mode`** is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   `menu-bar.el`.
>
> `(menu-bar-mode &optional ARG)`
>
> Toggle display of a menu bar on each frame (Menu Bar mode).
>
> With a prefix argument `ARG`, enable Menu Bar mode if `ARG` is
>   positive, and disable it otherwise.  If called from Lisp, also
>   enable Menu Bar mode if `ARG` is omitted or `nil`.
>
> This command applies to all frames that exist and frames to be
>   created in the future.

So to turn it off using Lisp, for example in your init file (`~/.emacs`), you can do this:

`(menu-bar-mode -1)`

That description of turning the mode on/off interactively and from Lisp is general for minor modes.

Unfortunately, that doc string does not tell you that `menu-bar-mode` is a minor mode or that minor modes generally follow the same rules for turning them on/off. But if you click the link in that `*Help*` output to go to the definition of `menu-bar-mode` in `menu-bar.el` then you'll see that it's defined using macro `define-minor-mode`.

And `C-h f define-minor-mode` gives you general information about turning on/off a minor mode.